# What is the meaning of using EUID?If RUID and EUID of a process is 1000, 0 and if we run any command the command is run as 1000 priviledge level,why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, permissions, setuid

As per my understanding,

- **RUID**: uid of the caller of the process is called real uid.
- **EUID**: effective uid means allowed privilege for that process.

```
// setuid_file.c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        int uid;
        uid=getuid();
        printf("RUID : getuid() : %d\n",uid);
        uid=geteuid();
        printf("EUID : geteuid() : %d\n",uid);

        system("whoami");
        system("cat /etc/sudoers"); //only root user can access. here we can write any command which only root user can execute.
}
```

```
gcc setuid_file.c -o euid_zero
chmod ug+s euid_zero
```

So, on root terminal, I have set suid and guid for the euid_zero executable. Now, ff I try to run the executable using normal user, then below is the output.

```
ll euid_zero
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 16768 Dec 30 00:59 euid_zero

whoami
kali

id
uid=1000(kali) gid=1000(kali) groups=1000(kali)

./euid_zero

RUID : getuid() : 1000
EUID : geteuid() : 0
kali
cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

So, here EUID is zero then also we can not gain root privilege. So, that means we have access privilege according to RUID, then what is the meaning of EUID if there is no use of EUID?

Answer (score 1):

It allows the process to *temporarily* raise and lower privileges as it needs.

For example, a file-server daemon (smbd, ftpd) starts as root, but then seteuid()'s to the logged-in user's EUID. Now it can run most of the time with the logged-in user's EUID, letting the kernel apply file access checks, but still be able to raise its privileges back to EUID 0 for certain operations.

But note that when you use `system()`, this invokes the command through `/bin/sh`, **and the Bash shell deliberately drops privileges** whenever it detects an UID/EUID mismatch. Your own setuid process *could* in fact open `/etc/shadow` just fine – it's only tools launched through system() that won't be able to.

If you replace all system() calls with fork+exec, or even a simple `open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY)`, you will see that having RUID=1000 but EUID=0 allows you to access the file. (Additionally, you will also see `id` reporting both sets of UID/GID.)

Comment: True, except the OP's `sh` is likely `dash`, not `bash`. Interestingly, `dash` used to behave differently and `man 3 system` still describes the old behavior. See the links in my answer. Nowadays there is no difference in this matter and your answer may as well say "Dash".

Answer (score 1):

In general EUID itself works as you expect, the "problem" here is with `system(3)` and `sh` it uses. See the manual ([`man 3 system`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)):

> `system()` will not, in fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which `/bin/sh` is `bash` version 2: as a security measure, `bash` 2 drops privileges on startup. (Debian uses a different shell, `dash(1)`, which does not do this when invoked as `sh`.)

It turns out the manual is not up-to-date. Nowadays [`dash` behaves like `bash`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734869). Frankly, I don't know what shell your OS uses as `sh` (you tagged [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu), Ubuntu uses `dash`; but `kali` in your question may suggest Kali, I'm not sure what Kali uses). Check with `ls -l /bin/sh`, it's probably `dash`. Regardless what it is, it most likely drops privileges and this is the reason of `Permission denied` you observed.

Even if your `sh` didn't drop privileges, `system()` wouldn't be a good idea. The already linked manual explicitly disadvises it:

> Do not use `system()` from a privileged program (a set-user-ID or set-group-ID program, or a program with capabilities) because strange values for some environment variables might be used to subvert system integrity.